# Get inputs value and separated by "|"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inputs and I need to get values and separated by `"|"` symbol.

My input:

[image]

Output what I need:

**00:00|00:00|00:00**

My code is :

(and it's not working)

```
var timesArray = $('table').find('input');
var times = timesArray.val();

$('.alltimes').val(times);
```

Comment: Your input is an image?

Comment: maybe you mean Javascript, not Java

Comment: Should re-post using [javascript] tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `.val` returns the value of each element (whatever input type it is in your screenshot), then you can use `.map`: http://jsfiddle.net/RrCYD/.

```
var values = $("input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();  // map each element to its value
}).get().join("|");        // get real array and join
```

Answer (score 3):

See comments in code:

```
// Create an array to store the input values
var inputValues = [];

// Iterate over input's and store their value in the array
$('table').find('input').each(function () {
   inputValues.push(this.value);
});

// Create pipe=delimited string from array of values
var delimitedInputValues = inputValues.join("|");
```

**Additional Information**

- MDN - [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- jQuery - [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)